# How to find and insert missing data without creating duplicates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem where I have a table with several daily indicators in which I post information about them daily, but there was an error this month where some dates were missing in these indicators, randomly follows the image below as an example:

```
select distinct fk_indicador_id, datareferencia, dataindicador FROM appweb_ind_exeindicadores where datareferencia = "2021-09-01" and fk_indicador_id = "61";

61  2021-09-01  2021-09-01
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-02
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-03
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-04
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-05
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-06
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-07
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-08
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-09
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-10
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-12
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-13
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-15
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-16
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-17
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-18
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-19
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-20
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-21
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-22
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-23
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-24
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-25
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-26
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-27
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-28
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-29
61  2021-09-01  2021-09-30
```

How do I make an insert in the entire table for the dates that are missing without duplicating?

Comment: So the task is to find the minimum date and maximum date for ind 61 in the table and then insert a row for every missing day between the two dates? Sounds like a task for a recursive query, which is available since MySQL 8. What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Is there a unique constraint on the combination of fk_indicador_id and dataindicador in your table? Or are duplicates generally allowed, but you just don't want to create any in this situation?

Comment: And please don't link to images, but paste the table data as text into your request. Read: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: In this case this is just an example of the 61 indicator, I have another 280 indicators with the same problem with random dates missing from the same table, yes I'm using Mysql8

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an insert select with a recursive query. The recursive query gets you all dates for all indicators. Then you insert those that are missing from the table.

```
insert into appweb_ind_exeindicadores (fk_indicador_id, dataindicador, datareferencia)
with recursive all_dates (fk_indicador_id, dataindicador, max_dataindicador) as
(
  select fk_indicador_id, min(dataindicador), max(dataindicador)
  from appweb_ind_exeindicadores
  group by fk_indicador_id
  union all
  select fk_indicador_id, dataindicador + interval 1 day, max_dataindicador
  from all_dates
  where dataindicador < max_dataindicador
)
select
  fk_indicador_id,
  dataindicador,
  dataindicador - interval (day(dataindicador) - 1) day as datareferencia
from all_dates
where (fk_indicador_id, dataindicador) not in
(
  select fk_indicador_id, dataindicador from appweb_ind_exeindicadores
);
```

Comment: Error Code: 3636. Recursive query aborted after 1001 iterations. Try increasing @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value.

Comment: this table have 138362 row(s)

Comment: The error probably means that there are more than 1000 days between some indicator's min date and max date. Have you tried to set this to a larger value? In the docs they show how to set this up from 1000 to a million: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursion-limits.. Or, if you are not interested in gaps in old data or you know there exist none, start with a higher date, e.g. `greatest(min(dataindicador), date '2020-09-01')` instead of `min(dataindicador)`.